# Transforming an Element on Hover of a Different Element

Tags: css, transform, transition

I have an image I would like to apply a css transitioned rotate transformation to when I mouse over an "a" tag in a separate area of the page. The only element I've thus far been able to target with this rotate is the image itself on hover over the image:

```
section#logo img {
        -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: -o-transform 5s ease-out;        
        transition: transform 5s ease-out;
    }

    section#logo img:hover {
        -ms-transform: rotate(1800deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1800deg);
        transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
```

What I want to do is something like this but I can't get it to function properly.

```
nav a:hover {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 5s ease-out;
        -moz-transition: -moz-transform 5s ease-out;
        -o-transition: -o-transform 5s ease-out;        
        transition: transform 5s ease-out;
    }

    section#logo img {
        -ms-transform: rotate(1800deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(1800deg);
        transform: rotate(1800deg);
    }
```

Markup:

```
    <nav>
          <a href="/page1.html">Click</a>
    </nav>
    <section id="logo">
          <img src="images/item.png" />
    </section>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Can we see your markup? It heavily depends on the order/relationship of your elements whether this can be done in CSS or if you'll need to use Javascript.

Comment: I have provided it. Thank you.

Comment: I think the only way is doing by javascript adding/removin css class to the image

Comment: When and what classes would I need to add and remove from the image?